# Storing a screenshot and uploading it from a browser-based app to a web server

Tags: c#, file-upload, unity-game-engine, screenshot, playmaker

So I'm just looking for a quick primer on how I can upload a screenshot to a web server from a browser-based app. Since I can't save the file locally and then upload it, do I need to store it in a texture variable? I'm a little confused on the basics of this but I'm only looking to get pointed in the right direction. Everything I've researched online addresses using a string variable that points to the file location locally, but this won't work for a browser based app, correct? Just looking for some guidance on how to start building a POC for this. Thanks for the help.

What I know:
I can take the screenshot (but right now I only know how to save it to locally)
I can upload a file (but only from a local path)

Big question:
How do I do I save the screenshot only in memory? Not sure if that's even the correct question but I hope someone knows what I'm trying to get at.

Ultimately what I want to do is take a screenshot and then save it directly to a mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity help page for Texture2D.EncodeToPNG has a complete example for capturing and uploading a screenshot.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.EncodeToPNG.html

```
// Saves screenshot as PNG file.
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class PNGUploader : MonoBehaviour {
    // Take a shot immediately
    IEnumerator Start () {
        yield return UploadPNG();
    }

    IEnumerator UploadPNG() {
        // We should only read the screen buffer after rendering is complete
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
        int width = Screen.width;
        int height = Screen.height;
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

        // Read screen contents into the texture
        tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 0, 0);
        tex.Apply();

        // Encode texture into PNG
        byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
        Object.Destroy(tex);

        // For testing purposes, also write to a file in the project folder
        // File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/../SavedScreen.png", bytes);


        // Create a Web Form
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("frameCount", Time.frameCount.ToString());
        form.AddBinaryData("fileUpload",bytes);

        // Upload to a cgi script
        WWW w = new WWW("http://localhost/cgi-bin/env.cgi?post", form);
        yield return w;

        if (w.error != null) {
            Debug.Log(w.error);
        } else {
            Debug.Log("Finished Uploading Screenshot");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, cool.  I dropped that code into a new cs file and attached it to a save button. I see 'IEnumerator Start ()' at the the top of the script. Does that means it should run as soon as the app starts? I'm not getting any feedback in the Console at the moment that things are succeeded or failing. What do I need to do to execute this script?

Comment: Yes, Start means it will run immediately upon startup. To attach to a button, you would need to remove the Start function and put the following instead:

    `void TakeScreenshot() {
        StartCoroutine("UploadPNG");
   }`

After that, attach the button's OnClick handler to TakeScreenshot in the inspector. Of course, you still need to code your specific upload logic to your own URL, since it is currently sending data to an example URL.